# In SwiftUI how to pass Fetched object to DetailView in CoreData

Tags: macos, core-data, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I'm new to SwiftUI and CoreData and I try to implement persistence with CoreData in my `macos` app. Now I stuck with managing to pass the selected item from the `SidebarView` to the `DetailView` within a `NavigationSplitView`.
The non-persistent `ObservableObject` `DataStore` is replaced with the persistent `UserDataModel` holding the entities `User` and `SecretItem`.

How do I pass the selected `User` in the `SidebarView` to the `SecretDetailView` to show the the details of the selected user?
Thanks!

my `ContentView`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

 @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)])
 private var users: FetchedResults<User>

 //@EnvironmentObject var dataStore: DataStore   <-- old non-persistante Datastore
 @State private var selectedUserID: User.ID?
 @State private var defaultUserID: User.ID?


 var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        SidebarView(selection: selection)
        
    } detail: {
        SecretDetailView(user: selectedUser)
    }
 }

 private var selection: Binding<User.ID?> {
    Binding(get: { selectedUserID ?? defaultUserID }, set: { selectedUserID = $0 })
 }

 private var selectedUser: Binding<User> {
    //$dataStore[selection.wrappedValue]
    ???                                       <-- here I'm struggling
 }
```

my `SecretDetailView`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecretDetailView: View {

 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
 @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.userName)])

 var secretItem: FetchedResults<SecretItem>
 @Binding var user: User                      <-- the Binding used in ContentView

 @State var searchText: String = ""
 @State private var selection = Set<SecretItem.ID>()

 @State var sortOrder: [KeyPathComparator<SecretItem>] = [
    .init(\.userName, order: SortOrder.forward)
 ]

 var table: some View {
    Table(selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
        TableColumn("User Name", value: \.userName)
 ...
 
 var body: some View {
    
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        
        table
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .navigationTitle(user.name!)
            //.navigationSubtitle("file: kpoph")
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some further help and reading I found the answer myself.

In ContentView the user is passed to the SecretDetailView as follows:

```
private var selectedUser: User {
    users.filter({ $0.id == selection.wrappedValue }).first! 
}
```

But this is not enough and will still throw an error. Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855920/cannot-convert-return-expression-of-type-fetchedresultsuser-element-aka-o) `Binding` is not to be used for `FetchRequest` `/NSManagedObject`. In the SecretItemView `ObservedObject` is the right choice:

```
@ObservedObject var user: User
```

Hope I can help others with similar issues.